# Converting Lat Lon points to line, then calculating distance travelled in QGIS

Tags: point, line, length

I understand this question, or variations thereof, gets asked regularly but no matter what I try I can't seem to convert points from GPS tracks to lines, then calculate the distances travelled. This is all in an attempt to quantify effort while on marine mammal surveys.

The data have been saved as .CSV files and are composed of four headings: Date, Time, Longitude and Latitude (as per fig).

I have attempted to use the "points to path" function in the toolkit, but the first and last points appear to become connected. This would give an incorrect measurement of the distance we travelled while on effort if I measured this path with this connecting line.

Is there a way to:

1. create the line from the points without joining the 1st and last points, then
2. measure this line to know how far we travelled?

[image]

Comment: *"points to path"* sounds to me that your attempts were done in QGIS, is not it? Please, add a relevant tag [tag:qgis] into your question

Comment: Keep in mind that: you can tick/untick *Create closed paths [optional]* which is available from QGIS 3.16

Comment: Please always include links to any earlier questions from this site that you mention in your question.